# Ipywidgets are not displayed with JavaScript error

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets, jupyterhub

We are currently using JupyterHub for our team. When I try to use ipywidgets in JupyterLab I get this JavaScript error (https adress is cutted out)

The Code

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

slider = widgets.FloatSlider(description='$x$')
text = widgets.FloatText(disabled=True, description='$x^2$')

def compute(*ignore):
    text.value = str(slider.value ** 2)

slider.observe(compute, 'value')

slider.value = 4

widgets.VBox([slider, text])
```

The error from the notebook:

```
[Open Browser Console for more detailed log - Double click to close this message]
Failed to load model class 'VBoxModel' from module '@jupyter-widgets/controls'
Error: Module @jupyter-widgets/controls, version ^1.5.0 is not registered, however,         2.0.0 is
    at f.loadClass (/lab/extensions/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager/static/134.bcbea9feb6e7c4da7530.js?v=bcbea9feb6e7c4da7530:1:74977)
    at f.loadModelClass (/lab/extensions/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager/static/150.3e1e5adfd821b9b96340.js?v=3e1e5adfd821b9b96340:1:10729)
    at f._make_model (/lab/extensions/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager/static/150.3e1e5adfd821b9b96340.js?v=3e1e5adfd821b9b96340:1:7517)
    at f.new_model (/lab/extensions/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager/static/150.3e1e5adfd821b9b96340.js?v=3e1e5adfd821b9b96340:1:5137)
    at f.handle_comm_open (/lab/extensions/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager/static/150.3e1e5adfd821b9b96340.js?v=3e1e5adfd821b9b96340:1:3894)
    at _handleCommOpen (/lab/extensions/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager/static/134.bcbea9feb6e7c4da7530.js?v=bcbea9feb6e7c4da7530:1:73393)
    at b._handleCommOpen (/static/lab/jlab_core.c53d87cd566b4851041c.js?v=c53d87cd566b4851041c:2:1203616)
    at async b._handleMessage (/static/lab/jlab_core.c53d87cd566b4851041c.js?v=c53d87cd566b4851041c:2:1205606)
```

This is the error in the browser console (https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9wJS.png)

The packages:

```
Package                       Version
----------------------------- ------------
absl-py                       1.3.0
aiohttp                       3.8.3
aiosignal                     1.3.1
alembic                       1.8.1
altair                        4.2.0
anyio                         3.6.2
appmode                       0.8.0
argon2-cffi                   21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings          21.2.0
asn1crypto                    1.5.1
asttokens                     2.1.0
astunparse                    1.6.3
async-generator               1.10
async-timeout                 4.0.2
attrs                         22.1.0
Babel                         2.11.0
backcall                      0.2.0
backports.functools-lru-cache 1.6.4
beautifulsoup4                4.11.1
bleach                        5.0.1
blinker                       1.5
bokeh                         3.0.2
boto3                         1.26.16
botocore                      1.29.16
Bottleneck                    1.3.5
brotlipy                      0.7.0
cached-property               1.5.2
cachetools                    5.2.0
certifi                       2022.9.24
certipy                       0.1.3
cffi                          1.15.1
charset-normalizer            2.1.1
click                         8.1.3
cloudpickle                   2.2.0
colorama                      0.4.6
comm                          0.1.0
conda                         22.9.0
conda-package-handling        1.9.0
contourpy                     1.0.6
cryptography                  38.0.3
cycler                        0.11.0
Cython                        0.29.32
cytoolz                       0.12.0
dask                          2022.11.0
debugpy                       1.6.3
decorator                     5.1.1
defusedxml                    0.7.1
dill                          0.3.6
distributed                   2022.11.0
ecdsa                         0.18.0
enbw-aop-client               0.20221027.1
entrypoints                   0.4
entsoe-py                     0.5.8
envs                          1.4
et-xmlfile                    1.0.1
executing                     1.2.0
fastjsonschema                2.16.2
filelock                      3.8.0
Flask                         2.2.2
flatbuffers                   2.0
flit_core                     3.8.0
fonttools                     4.38.0
frozenlist                    1.3.3
fsspec                        2022.11.0
gast                          0.4.0
geographiclib                 1.52
geopy                         2.3.0
gitdb                         4.0.9
GitPython                     3.1.29
gmpy2                         2.1.2
google-auth                   2.14.1
google-auth-oauthlib          0.4.6
google-pasta                  0.2.0
gravis                        0.1.0
greenlet                      2.0.1
grpcio                        1.47.1
h11                           0.14.0
h5py                          3.7.0
HeapDict                      1.0.1
idna                          3.4
imagecodecs                   2022.9.26
imageio                       2.22.4
importlib-metadata            5.0.0
importlib-resources           5.10.0
ipykernel                     6.18.0
ipython                       8.6.0
ipython-genutils              0.2.0
ipywidgets                    7.6.5
itsdangerous                  2.1.2
jedi                          0.18.2
Jinja2                        3.1.2
jmespath                      1.0.1
joblib                        1.2.0
json5                         0.9.10
jsonschema                    4.17.1
jupyter_client                7.4.1
jupyter_core                  5.0.0
jupyter-server                1.23.3
jupyter-server-mathjax        0.2.6
jupyter-server-proxy          3.2.2
jupyter-telemetry             0.1.0
jupyterhub                    3.0.0
jupyterlab                    3.5.0
jupyterlab-git                0.39.3
jupyterlab-pygments           0.2.2
jupyterlab_server             2.16.3
jupyterlab-widgets            1.1.1
keras                         2.10.0
Keras-Preprocessing           1.1.2
kiwisolver                    1.4.4
libmambapy                    1.0.0
llvmlite                      0.39.1
locket                        1.0.0
lxml                          4.9.1
lz4                           4.0.2
Mako                          1.2.4
mamba                         1.0.0
Markdown                      3.4.1
MarkupSafe                    2.1.1
matplotlib                    3.6.2
matplotlib-inline             0.1.6
mistune                       0.8.4
mpmath                        1.2.1
msgpack                       1.0.4
multidict                     6.0.2
munkres                       1.1.4
nbclassic                     0.4.8
nbclient                      0.5.13
nbconvert                     6.5.3
nbdime                        3.1.1
nbformat                      5.7.0
nbtools                       21.12
nest-asyncio                  1.5.6
networkx                      2.8.8
neurolab                      0.3.5
notebook                      6.5.2
notebook_shim                 0.2.2
ntlm-auth                     1.5.0
numba                         0.56.4
numexpr                       2.8.3
numpy                         1.23.5
oauthlib                      3.2.2
openpyxl                      3.0.10
opt-einsum                    3.3.0
oscrypto                      1.2.1
outcome                       1.2.0
packaging                     21.3
pamela                        1.0.0
pandas                        1.5.2
pandocfilters                 1.5.0
parso                         0.8.3
partd                         1.3.0
patsy                         0.5.3
pexpect                       4.8.0
pickleshare                   0.7.5
Pillow                        9.2.0
pip                           22.3.1
pkgutil_resolve_name          1.3.10
platformdirs                  2.5.4
plotly                        5.11.0
pretty-html-table             0.9.11
prometheus-client             0.15.0
prompt-toolkit                3.0.33
protobuf                      4.21.9
psutil                        5.9.4
ptyprocess                    0.7.0
pure-eval                     0.2.2
pyarrow                       9.0.0
pyasn1                        0.4.8
pyasn1-modules                0.2.7
pycognito                     2022.4.0
pycosat                       0.6.4
pycparser                     2.21
pycryptodomex                 3.15.0
pycurl                        7.45.1
pydantic                      1.10.2
Pygments                      2.13.0
PyJWT                         2.6.0
pyOpenSSL                     22.1.0
pyparsing                     3.0.9
pyproj                        3.4.0
pyrsistent                    0.19.2
PySocks                       1.7.1
python-dateutil               2.8.2
python-jose                   3.3.0
python-json-logger            2.0.1
pytz                          2022.6
pytz-deprecation-shim         0.1.0.post0
pyu2f                         0.1.5
PyWavelets                    1.3.0
PyYAML                        6.0
pyzmq                         24.0.1
requests                      2.28.1
requests-ntlm                 1.1.0
requests-oauthlib             1.3.1
requests-toolbelt             0.10.1
rpy2                          3.5.6
rsa                           4.9
ruamel.yaml                   0.17.21
ruamel.yaml.clib              0.2.7
ruamel-yaml-conda             0.15.80
s3transfer                    0.6.0
scikit-image                  0.19.3
scikit-learn                  1.1.3
scipy                         1.9.3
seaborn                       0.12.1
selenium                      4.6.0
Send2Trash                    1.8.0
setuptools                    65.6.2
SharePlum                     0.5.1
simpervisor                   0.4
simplegeneric                 0.8.1
six                           1.16.0
smmap                         3.0.5
sniffio                       1.3.0
snowflake-connector-python    2.8.2
sortedcontainers              2.4.0
soupsieve                     2.3.2.post1
SQLAlchemy                    1.4.44
stack-data                    0.6.1
statsmodels                   0.13.5
sympy                         1.11.1
tables                        3.7.0
tblib                         1.7.0
tenacity                      8.1.0
tensorboard                   2.10.1
tensorboard-data-server       0.6.0
tensorboard-plugin-wit        1.8.1
tensorflow                    2.10.0
tensorflow-estimator          2.10.0
termcolor                     2.1.1
terminado                     0.17.0
terminaltables                3.1.10
threadpoolctl                 3.1.0
tifffile                      2022.10.10
tinycss2                      1.2.1
tomli                         2.0.1
toolz                         0.12.0
tornado                       6.2
tqdm                          4.64.1
traitlets                     5.5.0
trio                          0.21.0
trio-websocket                0.9.2
typing_extensions             4.4.0
tzdata                        2022.6
tzlocal                       4.2
unicodedata2                  15.0.0
urllib3                       1.26.13
usp.common.data               5.1.1
usp.common.util               0.0.1
voila                         0.4.0
wcwidth                       0.2.5
webencodings                  0.5.1
websocket-client              1.4.2
websockets                    10.4
Werkzeug                      2.2.2
wheel                         0.38.4
widgetsnbextension            3.5.2
wrapt                         1.14.1
wsproto                       1.2.0
xlrd                          2.0.1
XlsxWriter                    3.0.3
xyzservices                   2022.9.0
yarl                          1.8.1
zict                          2.2.0
zipp                          3.10.0
```

I have already tried both versions of this solution `ipywidgets==7.6.5 or ipywidgets==7.7.2` [ipywidgets < 8 e.g. 7.7 cannot be installed with pip · Issue #3558 · jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets · GitHub](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/3558#issuecomment-1221309944)

The individual environment for each user (from Zero to JupyterHub solution) starts with `ipywidgets==8.0.2`. The problem is that we may need another version `<8`, due to your problem with voila [Nbconvert and voila no ipywidgets - General - Jupyter Community Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/nbconvert-and-voila-no-ipywidgets/16800)

Cross-post https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/ipywidgets-are-not-displayed-with-javascript-error/16958

Comment: By chance, have you find any solution to this ? I am facing the same issue....

Comment: Same here, would love to know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer:

It seems like this issue is related to upgrading to jupyterlab 4. I had perfect code. The FileChooser from ipyfilechooser worked. A little box would appear beneath the cell, I'd click the box, and then I could select a file (or in my case, a folder). Now I get that same javascript error.

If I take the following steps, I can get it to work:

1. don't use a conda installed kernel
2. uninstall/reinstall ipyfilechooser
3. reimport FileChooser (from ipyfilechooser import FileChooser)
4. Try it.

However, if I use a conda installed kernel (which I have to), uninstalling/reinstalling has no effect.

Comment: I know you don't have enough Rep to comment, and that's frustrating because you want to help.  You might could turn this into an answer with a little more info.  First, *"I had perfect code"* - Do you mean that *"My code was working in (the previous version"*?  If so that would be a more clear way to say it.  Also, if you downgrade to the previous version (if that's possible), does the problem go away?  If so, then you might have a proposed *workaround*, even if it may not be the best option.  That would then be "an answer".

Comment: If your statement was a bit more clear, I'd flag it and request a Moderator convert it to a comment, since it might be useful information.  You can edit it, flag it yourself, and request this, but no guarantees it will happen.